# Spring MVC + HIbernate ManyToMany mapping , delete cascade self join

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two tables

### Users

### Id  |  Name

1  | User 1

2  | User 2

### User_Helper

user_id | helper_id

1       |   2

The user_id & helper_id are referenced id from users table.

Now, when I delete the user 1, the entry is deleted from Mapping table. But when I delete 2 , i get exception saying, it has been referenced in mapping table

This is my entity code

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "user_helper", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "helper_id", updatable = false)})
    private Set<Users> helpers;
```

What am I missing

Comment: Table user_helper haven't row with user_id = 2

Answer (score 0):

When deleting helper, you must first remove it from any Users that reference it. That will clear the references to it from join table.

```
user.getHelpers().remove(helper);
session.delete(helper);
```

Comment: Can you check that after calling `remove()` the helper is actually removed from the set? Also, `user` should be managed object in order for this to work.

Comment: No.. whatever ur code does, is implicitly done by cascade itself. The helpers are removed with no hassle, the problem is while removing users who are in helper columns. Some how I got it working, not sure if its the right way.. posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding one more mapping line in Users entity as

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "user_helper", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "helper_id", updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false)})
private Set<Users> users;
```

and before deleting, i clear the users

```
userEntity.getUsers().clear(); // so, if there are any users associated with helpers, it will be cleared from mapping table
userEntityDAO.delete(userEntity);
```